# Problems with the task about if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, arraylist

I am a beginner in Java, please be easy to me.

I've got a task : People in the line are going to buy tickets. They have money three tipes: 25,50,100. Ticket costs - 25. If cashier has odd money - he gives a ticket, if not- doesn't.

How to make if for situation when in cash box are enough money with tipe 25 (25+25+25 ), but no one with tipe 50, and cashier get 100 from somebody?

My code:

```
public static void line(Integer... people) {
    ArrayList<Integer> cashbox = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int money : people) {
        if (money == 25) {
            cashbox.add(money);
            System.out.println("Here is your ticket!");
            continue;
        } else if (money == 50 && cashbox.contains(25)) {
            System.out.println("Here is your ticket!");
            cashbox.remove(cashbox.indexOf(25));
            continue;
        } else if (money == 100 && cashbox.contains(50) && cashbox.contains(25)) {
            System.out.println("Here is your ticket!");
            cashbox.remove(cashbox.indexOf(50));
            cashbox.remove(cashbox.indexOf(25));
            continue;
        }
        else {System.out.println("Sorry, I haven't odd money for you!");}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to check whether you got at least 3 banknotes of 25 money. You can do it by filter your cashbox ArrayList for this value and check if it contains >= 3 results.

```
cashbox.stream().filter(money -> money == 25).count() >= 3
```

so in the end what you would need to do is to add another else if to your code:

```
else if (money == 100 && cashbox.stream().filter(money -> money == 25).count() >= 3) {
    System.out.println("Here is your ticket!");
    cashbox.remove(cashbox.indexOf(25));
    cashbox.remove(cashbox.indexOf(25));
    cashbox.remove(cashbox.indexOf(25));
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear why `ArrayList` is needed as a cashbox, it can be replaced with three counters for each type of bank notes, and checking/modifying the values of these counters.  Multiple searches in the list using `contains/indexOf` are far from optimal.

Similarly, these counters might be organized into a map, where type of money is a key and the amount of each note is the value.

Also, it's worth mentioning that the initial code does not add notes of 50 and 100 upon selling a ticket :)

Example of a map-based cashbox is as follows:

```java
public static void line(int ... people) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> cashbox = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int money : people) {
        boolean ok = false;
        String change = "";
        
        switch (money) {
            case 25: 
                ok = true; break;
            case 50: 
                ok = cashbox.getOrDefault(25, 0) > 0;
                if (ok) {
                    cashbox.put(25, cashbox.get(25) - 1);
                    change = "25";
                }
                break;
            case 100:
                ok = cashbox.getOrDefault(50, 0) > 0 && cashbox.getOrDefault(25, 0) > 0 || cashbox.getOrDefault(25, 0) > 2;
                if (ok) {
                    if (cashbox.getOrDefault(50, 0) > 0) {
                        cashbox.put(50, cashbox.get(50) - 1);
                        cashbox.put(25, cashbox.get(25) - 1);
                        change = "50+25 = 75";
                    } else {
                        cashbox.put(25, cashbox.get(25) - 3);
                        change = "3*25 = 75";
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        if (ok) {
            cashbox.compute(money, (pay, count) -> count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
            System.out.println("Here is your ticket" + (change.isEmpty() ? "" : " and change " + change) + "!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, I haven't odd money for your " + money);
        }
    }
    // remove "empty" counters
    cashbox.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue() == 0);
    System.out.println("cashbox: " + cashbox);
}
```

Test and output

```java
line(25, 25, 50, 100, 50, 25, 25, 100, 25, 100);
```

```
Here is your ticket!
Here is your ticket!
Here is your ticket and change 25!
Here is your ticket and change 50+25 = 75!
Sorry, I haven't odd money for your 50
Here is your ticket!
Here is your ticket!
Sorry, I haven't odd money for your 100
Here is your ticket!
Here is your ticket and change 3*25 = 75!
cashbox: {100=2}
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool)) thanks) honestly,  I know nothing about  "map "yet, I'm beginner in the cube 